# Button not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a javascript exercise to create a guessing game. I'm doing a bit of testing of the function before moving onto the next stage but this isn't working. When you click the button it's not giving the pop-up "Right Answer!". Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var userguess = "5";
var answer = "5"; 

function Guess(){
if (userguess==answer){

alert("right answer!");
} else {

alert("wrong answer!");
} 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="Guess" type="text" />
<button name="button" onClick="Guess()">Click me</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `onclick` use lowercase C

Comment: @Matjaž, you don't have to guess just because the question is about a guessing game.

Comment: because when you are clicking on the button the form is submitted and the page reloads.

Comment: Ashad is right, use `<button type="button"`> to alleviate this (or use the side effect in Developer's answer).

Comment: I've changed it to the above and now getting Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function when debugging in Chrome. This is on this line: <button type="button" type="button" onClick="Guess()">Click me</button>

Comment: "object is not a function" could be because your element's ID is "Guess" as well as your function name is "Guess" so, probably changing the name of function should give you right results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems:

- The button action is "submit" change it with:
  `type="button"`
- Your input has the id "Guess", this conflicts with the function name.

So when you change the type of the button and rename the function it will work.

Answer (score 3):

When you click on button that is inside form, it will submit form and page will reload. To fix that, use `type="button"`. It will prevent button to act as submit button

```
<form>
    <input id="Guess" type="text" />
    <button name="button" type="button" onClick="Guess()">Click me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I've altered the code to this but it doesn't seem to be giving me the pop-up still and when debugging in chrome i'm getting: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function. This is on this line: <button type="button" type="button" onClick="Guess()">Click me</button>

Comment: This answer is correct but solves only one of the two problems this code has. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's your `form` it's trying to submit the value:

http://jsfiddle.net/70ag6ang/

```
<head>
   <script>
     var userguess = "5";
     var answer = "5"; 

     function Guess(event){

     if (userguess==answer){

          alert("right answer!");
      } else {

     alert("wrong answer!");
    } 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="Guess" type="text" />
<button name="button" onclick="Guess()">Click me</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the button triggers the form to be submitted.

Also, you could use `addEventListener` method:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    var userguess = "5";
    var answer = "5"; 

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      document.querySelector('.my-button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (userguess==answer){
          alert("right answer!");
        } else {
          alert("wrong answer!");
        } 
      });
    }, false);

    </script>
  </head>
<body>
    <form>
      <input id="Guess" type="text" />
      <button name="button" class="my-button">Click me</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The first `addEventListener` listens when all the DOM element were added. Alternatively, you can put your `<script>` tag after `<body>` element.

The second one listens to `click` event on your element that you found using `document.querySelector`. Note, that I've added a class `my-button` to the element.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is  the Function name  conflicts with the input id

Try following code

**Html**

```
<body>
<form>
<input id="Guess" type="text" />
<button name="button" type="button" onClick="guess()">Click me</button>
</form>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
var userguess = "5";
var answer = "5"; 

function guess(){
if (userguess==answer){

alert("right answer!");
} else {

alert("wrong answer!");
} 
}
```

You can check Here

http://jsfiddle.net/L1x184nk/

Comment: Doesn't work when onclick event handler changed from `guess` to `Guess`!

Comment: Yes, because it conflicts with the input id. See my answer.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar yes Johni is correct , If you want to use Guess juest change id of text field, anyway normally javascript functions are starting with small letters

Comment: You could also use some kind of prefix for html elements.
For example: txtGuess, btnSend etc.
Yes it's stolen from Visual Basic ;-)

Answer (score -2):

```js
    var userguess = "5";
    var answer = "5";
    function GuessFn() {

      if (userguess == answer) {

        alert("right answer!");
      } else {

        alert("wrong answer!");
      }
    }
```

```html
    <form>
      <input id="Guess" type="text"/>
      <button name="button" onclick="GuessFn()">Click me</button>
    </form>
```

UPDATE: After reading through comments in OP thread I noticed his Element ID is "Guess" as well as the function name is "Guess" so this could be the reason behind "object is not a function" error. I also removed my ambiguous statement as in discussion below in comments to my answer.

Comment: he says his function is not getting fired, not if condition inside it

Comment: Okay, I probably made an ambiguous statement for which I got the negatives. What I meant to say is `===` compares values but also the type of variable. `==` compares by converting to common type [info here](http://conceptf1.blogspot.sg/2014/01/javascript-triple-equals-vs-double-equals-operators.html). But anyways you're right OP is asking his function is not getting fired onclick.